# Gradle-MercurialMqPlug gradle - missing pom

Tags: plugins, mercurial, gradle

I am new to Gradle build tool. I am trying to write my first build.gradle script.
I am trying to install Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin as described at https://bitbucket.org/coherentsoftware/gradle-mercurialmqplugin/overview
Also I am trying to do HgClone.
But when I run `gradle --info` I am getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradle'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find au.com.coherentsoftware.gradle:Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin:VERSION.
 Required by:
     :gradle:unspecified
```

Info also says:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/au/com/coherentsoftware/gradle/Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin/VERSION/Gradle-MercurialMqPlug
in-VERSION.pom]  
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/au/com/coherentsoftware/gradle/Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin/VERSION/Gradle-MercurialMqPlu
gin-VERSION.jar]
```

Could you please advise, what am I missing? Should I install some additional maven stuff or ...?
Is it possible that file is just actually missing, because when I enter that address in my browser it says:

```
Path 'bintray/jcenter/v1/content/bintray/jcenter/au/com/coherentsoftware/gradle/Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin/VERSION/Gradle-MercurialMqPlu gin-VERSION.jar' was not found.
```

And also for pom:

```
Path 'bintray/jcenter/v1/content/bintray/jcenter/au/com/coherentsoftware/gradle/Gradle-MercurialMqPlugin/VERSION/Gradle-MercurialMqPlug in-VERSION.pom' was not found.
```

Should I replace VERSION in this string or something like that?
EDIT
[I tried to replace VERSION with the latest tag V1.1.0, but I still got the same not found error when putting it in the browser]

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

mismas

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I replaced VERSION with 1.1.0 (NOT V1.1.0) :)
Just needed to sleep it over.
Silly error.